# error in class indentation practicing on terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and I am practicing writing classes in terminal

I wrote following

```
>>> class Calculator:
...     def calculate(self,expression):
...         self.value=eval(expression)
...  class Talker:
```

as soon as I typed `class Talker:` as above
I get following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 4
    class Talker:
                ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I am unable to understand why is this indentation error coming? How do I proceed from here.
**Based on updates**
I corrected the error and now I wrote the following

```
 class Calculator:
...     def calculate(self,evaluate):
...         self.value=eval(expression)
...     class Talker:
...         def talk(self):
...             print 'Hi, my value is ', self.value
...         class TalkingCalculator(Calculator,Talker):
...             pass
...
```

Now I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in Calculator
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in Talker
NameError: name 'Calculator' is not defined
```

What is this error what did I missed here?

Comment: You have indented `class Talker` one space. Don't indent it at all.

Comment: I did what you suggested after seeing your comment but I got error File "<stdin>", line 4
    class Talker:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Why is this question down voted for closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have indented your `Talker` class to put in inside `Calculator` class, but with inconsistent indention with the methods of `Calculator` class.  The amount of spaces need to be consistent.

Nested classes are local in scope to the place where they are defined and are controlled though indentation.  Subclasses are classes that **inherit** the properties of the superclass.

It seems you do not want `Talker` to be a subclass or a nested class of `Calculator`, but have `TalkingCalculator` be a subclass of `Calculator` and `Talker`.

```
>>> class Calculator(object):
...     def calculate(self,evaluate):
...         self.value=eval(expression)
...
>>> class Talker(object):
...     def talk(self):
...         print 'Hi, my value is ', self.value
...
>>> class TalkingCalculator(Calculator, Talker):
...     pass
```

Comment: Hmmm class Talker has to be sub class of Calculator does your method makes it a subclass

Comment: @RegisteredUser  ah, it wasn't clear that you wanted Talker to be a subclass.  I have updated my example.

Comment: Thanks this worked let me know if there is an easy way to copy paste code on python command line in Ubuntu

Comment: @RegisteredUser anytime I go beyond something that is trivial to type in, I put it in a `.py` file, so I dont have to type it in over and over ;)  But to answer the question, if you have any text editor open, you should be able to copy and paste right into your ubuntu shell running python

Comment: I just saw your Note: I am actually learning python and this example talks about inheritance so sub class here is inheritance...sorry I do not understand the difference between them, I also updated the question

Comment: @RegisteredUser updated for question update

Comment: Ok the example is about multiple superclasses for a class class TalkingCalculator has 2 super classes Calculator and Talker

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel pointed out, assuming you want Talker to be a separate class, you need to keep it the same indentation as your first "class Calculator:" line, meaning no spaces between the "..." and "class Talker:".

Take a look at this for a more in-depth discussion of python indentation. http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html.

Comment: no it has to be a sub class

Comment: If you want it to be a subclass of Calculator, try:
"class Talker(Calculator):" instead of "class Talker:". More information [here](http://www.diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/defining_classes.html).

Comment: Subclass - inheritance, Inner class - what cmd showed above.